# Is there an easy way to copy the music from my computer to my mp3 player?

Tags: banshee, music, mp3

I mostly use Banshee.
Once I have imported a CD on my computer , it's not user friendly at all to simply copy it to my Creative Zen. I get error message ("Argument cannot be found").

Comment: drag and drop the songs you want onto your mp3 player

Comment: If you're getting an error message, you should probably report that as a bug.  See: http://banshee.fm/contribute/file-bugs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried "clementine music player" when you plugin a usb or mp3 device,just hi-light the music that you want right click and it should say copy to "device or usb" . I know its not banshee but it does the job of copying music over very well.

http://www.clementine-player.org/

Comment: Clementine is great. This is exactly what I was looking for. I especially love the browsing through "real" folders (and not obscure tagged files).

Comment: Great glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

First things first. Some questions as I have several Creative Mp3 players and not all of them work.

Have you enabled your banshee to recognise your Creative device?

Does it show up in Banshee when you plug it in?

If not does Ubuntu ask what you want to open it with when you plug it in.

If it is recognised in banshee you can click on the device and tell banshee to sync with it or drag and drop files in there. Like I said though it does depend on your Creative MP3 player.

Banshee has a plugin,libmtp, that 'should' work with most modern MP3 players

Hope that helps

Comment: Banshee does recognise my Creative device. It shows up in Banshee when I plug it in.
It seems to works well "sometimes" and not very well most of the time...

Answer (score 0):

I use [Guayadeque](http://guayadeque.org/). It can transcode music to change it's format and/or quality, change the name of the files, resize the cover and more. And then you can view your collection in many ways.